# Why number of heap is always 1?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windbg, heap-memory

I am using WinDbg to see number of heaps in the process by using, `dt _PEB @$peb`. I get following info,

```
+0x088 NumberOfHeaps    : 1
```

Now according to *Advanced Windows Debugging* book,

> Most applications implicitly use components that create their own
>   heaps. A great example is the C runtime, which creates its own heap
>   during initialization.

I add breakpoint at main, still I can see there is only one heap in process.

Secondly, I ran following code, still number of heap is 1.

```
BYTE* pAlloc1 = NULL;
BYTE* pAlloc2 = NULL;
HANDLE hProcessHeap = GetProcessHeap();
pAlloc1 = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(hProcessHeap, 0, 16);
pAlloc2 = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(hProcessHeap, 0, 1500);
```

Why I am not getting number of heap incremented in process?

Comment: You've made two allocations from the heap, but you haven't created a new heap. I know little of Windows, but presumably you'll only get a second heap if something calls [`HeapCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: a guess: with `HeapAlloc` you are allocating memory from process heap, but with `HeapCreate` you create a new private heap.

Comment: Pure logic dictates that the C runtime has to create the heap (way) before you reach `main`.

Comment: "A great example"? Why can't they say "A good example"? Or am I just getting old?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Sure. Then count must be at least 2.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That would be faulty logic. `HeapCreate` is used to create a second heap; the C runtime doesn't need to create the first heap as that's OS-provided.

Comment: @MSalters: it's not faulty. You said yourself, it doesn't do it. But if it would...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process starts, it has a single heap, the default process heap. That explains the count of 1. You can create new heaps by calling [`HeapCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366599.aspx). Should you do so you will see the heap count increase.

Comment: But C runtime creates own heap?

Comment: Apparently not any more. Presumably the book referred to some historic runtime.

Comment: Not "very historic" C runtime from VS 2012 an onwards use the default process heap. Earlier versions creates their own heap.

Comment: @KjellGunnar Not very sure, but when I used x64 bit it seems to create 2 heaps, and x86 creates only 1. But I need to check again tomorrow in office.

Comment: @pranitkothari  check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955871/why-does-get-heap-handle-equal-to-getprocessheap