# Access Violation error when PInvoke C function calls Win32 function that allocates memory

Tags: c#, c, winapi, pinvoke

I had written a library (which worked fine) in C# for running Win32 functions. Such as PInvoking CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials,CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer,CredPackAuthenticationBuffer, so one method call can return NetworkCredentials without you doing all the credential packing/unpacking and error checking youself. And similarly classes and methods for creating/listing/changing/removing local users and local groups from a computer using NetUser... and NetGroup... functions

```
//ToolsCS.cs

public static class Credentials{
    public static NetworkCredential GetCredentials(string promtpCaption, string promptMessage, string inUsername, string inDomain, string inPassword){...}
    public static NetworkCredential GetCredentials(string promtpCaption, string promptMessage){...}
}
public class User{
    public static User[] GetUsers(string computername){...}
    public static bool Exists(string computername,string username){...}
    public static void Create(string computername,User user){...}
    public static void Delete(string computername,string username){...}
    public static void Set(string computername,string username,User user){...}
    public string Name;
    public string DisplayName;
    public string Description;
}
```

This all works great for any other C# library or app that calls them.
Now I am writing a couple apps in C, which are using the same functions i just made my C# library for, so why not make it in C to use for these C apps, make writing the app itself simpler.

```
//ToolsC.c

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupList(wchar_t* system,wchar_t** names,DWORD* count);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupExists(wchar_t* system,wchar_t* name);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupCreate(wchar_t* system,wchar_t* name);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupSet(wchar_t* system,wchar_t* name);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupRemove(wchar_t* system,wchar_t* name);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupAddMember(wchar_t* system,wchar_t* group,wchar_t* member);
```

This all workds great for the apps im writing in C. But the trouble I get is when I decided to try calling these C functions i wrote from C#

```
//SomeApp.cs
class SomeClass{
    [DllImport(@"ToolsC.dll",SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool AccGroupList(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]                       string system,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeParamIndex=2)] ref string[] names,
                                                            ref int count);
    ...
}
```

When debugging the C# code, it successfully steps into my exported C dll function it crashes with a Access Violation error when it makes the call to `NetGroupEnum` (which in documentation says that the system allocates a buffer, not the caller) the same error crashes the C# app when it calls my C function the calls `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` (which also says the system allocates a buffer).
It's not that the Win32 functions return and then I get error when accessing the buffer it gave me, It's that the debugger gives me an error box without returning from that function.
For AccGroupExists, it uses `NetUserGetInfo` function, and only gets the user's name, returns wihtout crashing, this function fills a buffer you give it, not a "system allocated buffer".

I already tried changing the my exported C functions to have different parameter types, and allocating any strings inside the C function and copying the passed C# strings into the wchar_t* before calling the Win32 functions. And I tried changing the PInvoke parameter types.

So it seems like I have to settle for doing C#->Win32 for C#, and C->Win32 for C. But I cant use C#->C->Win32.

Is there something I can do in C# like setting the memory security or process access rights before I make calls to my C dll that will allow the Win32 functions to allocate memory without crashing the application?

**EDIT**

Here is a function in the C library, which works fine for me when called in another C app. But fails at `NetLocalGroupEnum` from C#.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall AccGroupList(wchar_t* system,wchar_t** names,DWORD* count){
    GROUP_INFO_0* buffer;
    DWORD readcount=0;
    DWORD totalcount=0;
    DWORD size=0;
    //C# app crashes here
    error=NetLocalGroupEnum(system,0,(LPBYTE*)&buffer,MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,&readcount,&totalcount,NULL);
    if(error!=NERR_Success){
        SetLastError(error);
        return FALSE;}
    if((names=(wchar_t**)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(wchar_t*)*readcount))==NULL){
        NetApiBufferFree(&buffer);
        SetLastError(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
        return FALSE;}
    for(int i=0;i<readcount;i++){
        size=wcslen(buffer[i].grpi0_name);
        if((names[i]=(wchar_t*)CoTaskMemAlloc(2*size))==NULL){
            for(int j=0;j<i;i++){
                size=wcslen(names[j]);
                wmemset(names[j],0,size);
                CoTaskMemFree(names[j]);}
            NetApiBufferFree(&buffer);
            CoTaskMemFree(names);
            SetLastError(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
            return FALSE;}
        
        wmemset(names[i],0,size);
        wcscpy(names[i],buffer[i].grpi0_name);}
    NetApiBufferFree(&buffer);
    *count=readcount;
    return TRUE;}
```

Comment: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex=2)]` Also how are you calling this code, are you preallocating the array buffer in C#?

Comment: @Charlieface the array gets allocated in the C function after calling the external windows function. But the array is not an argument to the call to the netapi32 library.

Comment: *"Crash"* means a lot of different things to a lot of people. What's the *specific* error you're observing. Also, if a function allocates resources, then those parameters should be `out` rather than `ref`.

Comment: @IInspectable if i run it from command prompt, it "crashes" as in it not only exits the the exe, but also closes the command prompt i ran it from. When using debugger, even if I wrap the pinvoke call in a try/catch, the debugger shows the "Access Violation" error, and then immediately closes the debugging session. I had tried, decorating the C function to have out for the parameters that are written to, and tried both ref and out for the pinvoke in c#

Comment: You can't allocate it in C as the C# side has no way of deallocating it. You must allocate and deallocate it on the same side, ie C# . And once you have done that you should do `[Out] string[] names` not `ref string[] names` ie remove the `ref`

Answer (score -1):

What you want from the C# side is get back a list of strings, the list being itself allocated by the native side, so you have to declare a pointer to an array (a pointer) of strings (a pointer), so the declaration should pass a triple pointer (plus there are some other issues in the code):

```
extern "C" BOOL __stdcall AccGroupList(wchar_t* system, wchar_t*** names, DWORD * count) {
    GROUP_INFO_0* buffer;
    DWORD readcount;
    DWORD totalcount;
    wchar_t** readnames;

    *names = NULL;
    *count = 0;
    DWORD error = NetLocalGroupEnum(system, 0, (LPBYTE*)&buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &readcount, &totalcount, NULL);
    if (error != NERR_Success) {
        SetLastError(error);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ((readnames = (wchar_t**)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(wchar_t*) * readcount)) == NULL) {
        NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
        SetLastError(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
        return FALSE;
    }

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < readcount; i++) {
        size_t size = wcslen(buffer[i].grpi0_name) + 1; // + 1 to account for terminating 0
        if ((readnames[i] = (wchar_t*)CoTaskMemAlloc(2 * size)) == NULL) {
            for (DWORD j = 0; j < i; j++) { // j++ instead of i++
                CoTaskMemFree(readnames[j]);
            }

            NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
            CoTaskMemFree(readnames);
            SetLastError(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
            return FALSE;
        }

        wcscpy(readnames[i], buffer[i].grpi0_name);
    }

    NetApiBufferFree(buffer); // free buffer, not pointer to it
    *names = readnames;
    *count = readcount;
    return TRUE;
}
```

And the C# should be like this (each string is unicode, so you must use `ArraySubType`, and variable parameters are `out`, since fully given by the native side):

```
[DllImport(@"ToolsC.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool AccGroupList(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string system,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string[] names,
    out int count);
```

Comment: How would C# free that memory? Would have thought it better to just allocate and free on the C# side only.

Comment: @Charlieface That would probably require passing a [`SAFEARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray), holding [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr)s. With that either side knows which allocator to use. An easier approach would be to create a mixed-mode interop assembly, using C++/CLI, that the .NET code can use to call into the native code.

Comment: @Charlieface - As long as you use the COM allocator, it's fine. On recent version of Windows, they're kinda all the same anyway https://stackoverflow.com/a/36423272/403671 on Linux (dotnet core) you can use malloc https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/10748

Comment: It was a platform issue, when I had the C and C# both in 32bit, it failed, but when I set them to both 64bit it worked. Not really sure why, since the NetGroupEnum is in netapi32, a 32bit library.

Comment: @Robot - It's clearly not (only) a platform issue

Comment: I was recreating the solution in visual studio to so I could put it on github, and post a link here. When I was making the first solution i fiddled with the project files for the C librarys a lot, but this time all i did was set everything to target x64, and it worked.