Send protobuf message as byte array from C++ to C#
I have a C# application and a C++ dll library. I want to make them communicate using protobuf. The C# app would be the caller and C++ the sender.
What I'm doing is the following:
caller.cs
public static class CppWrapper
{
    private const string InterfaceLibrary = "MyCppDll.dll";

    [DllImport(InterfaceLibrary, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "CppFunction"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern bool CppFunction([In] byte[] bytes, [In] int size);
}

MyProtobufMessage proto = new();
// Fill proto message

byte[] bytes = proto.ToByteArray();
bool success = CppWrapper.CppFunction(bytes, bytes.Length);

sender.hpp
extern "C" bool __declspec(dllexport) CppFunction(const void* bin, std::size_t size_bin);

sender.cpp
bool CppFunction(const void* bin, std::size_t size_bin)
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyProtobufMessage> proto = std::make_unique<MyProtobufMessage>();
    if (!proto->ParseFromArray(buffer, size))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Do things
    
    return true;
}

So far it works well. But what I want now is my C++ function CppFunction to send another protobuf object as byte array as an output for my C# app to process.
Something in the line of:
extern "C" bool __declspec(dllexport) CppFunction(const void* bin,
                                                  std::size_t size_bin,
                                                  void* bout, /* protobuf output as byte array */
                                                  std::size_t size_bout /* output array size */);

The thing is of course I don't know the output size in advance and everything. My question is more like, what is the best way to do it? (And as such, how should I also change the C# caller function?).

Do you have two applications/processes, which are communicating (IPC)? Or do you have single application/process which uses C# code (manged) and C++ code (native)? First case would explain why you using protobuf, second case use of protobuf looks strange, you should be able to build fast bridge between C++ and C# without protobuf, using C++CLI or simple marshaling.

@MarekR Yes I left that part out but yeah protobuf is needed here as I'm manipulating data.

If your question is how to use native data using a pointer and length in C#, you have a few easy options:

To get a byte[] managed array, you can use Marshal.Copy
To get a ReadOnlySpan<>, simply construct it from your pointer and length.


Do note that you will probably need a way to release that allocated memory, which most likely involves exposing another function from C++ that handles the deletion (delete[], free, etc).

As @Blindy mentioned, is there a way to do it without needing to have the deallocation counterpart on C++? If not then I'll go this way then thanks.

Depends entirely on how you make these calls. For example, the typical C function will receive the buffer to write into rather than allocate it itself, so the caller then has to both allocate it and free it. Of course this then raises the question of how much to allocate before even calling your function, and this is typically done in 2 passes (first make the function calculate the length and return it, then the caller allocates the array and passes it in to be filled). The Win32 API is full of these kinds of functions.

ffmpeg on the other hand, another very large, very infamous C library, will allocate memory when needed, then force the caller to call the correct free function that it also provides -- for example av_free or av_freep.

You can declare your C++ side like this and use an allocator common to C# and C++, for example here I use the COM allocator (note: today it's not that important https://stackoverflow.com/a/36423272/403671):
void __stdcall CppFunction(void** bout, std::size_t* size_bout)
{
    *size_bout = 10000;
    *bout = CoTaskMemAlloc(*size_bout); // COM allocator
}

And like this in C# (note a std::size_t strict equivalent is .NET's IntPtr):
[DllImport("mydll")]
private static extern void CppFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out byte[] bout, out IntPtr size);

...
CppFunction(out var bytes, out var size);

